# submit form not working with confirm box

Tags: javascript, submit, getelementbyid

I'm trying to create a scenario where dynamically generated

here's my javascript code:

```
        function confirmDelete( varForm ) {
            var r = confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this entry?");

            if (r == true) {
                document.getElementById("form" + varForm).submit();
            }
        }
```

and here's my php/html code:

```
        <form name="form<?php echo $x . $y; ?>" id="form<?php echo $x . $y; ?>" action="/index.php" method="post">
            <a href="#" onclick="confirmDelete(<?php echo $x . $y; ?>); return false;"><p><?php echo $aryClientInfo[$x][1][$y * 3]; ?></p></a>
            <input type="hidden" name="values<?php echo $x; ?>" value="<?php echo ($y * 3) . ',' . ($y * 3 + 1) . ',' . ($y * 3 + 2); ?>">
        </form>
```

it doesn't seem to submit the form and I don't know why (I've already verrified the the form name and the javascript function input variable match).  I've figured out that the function does get called and the confirm box does work as intended.  $x and $y are part of for loops that generate the multiple links from a MySQL database.

Comment: I just removed the return false; and it still doesn't work

Comment: @zgr024 that does not matter.

Comment: What is the error in the console? When you inspect the form, what is the actual id? If you do `console.log(varForm);` what does it output?

Comment: Does it submit without the confirmation?

Comment: console error - Cannot read property 'submit' of null

Comment: JavaScript error. Undefined variable. You need to put quotes inside the function call

Comment: if I use "document.form<?php echo $x . $y; ?>.submit();" for onclick, it will submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error is that you're passing the `varForm` without the quotes, try this:

```
<form name="form<?php echo $x . $y; ?>" id="form<?php echo $x . $y; ?>" action="/index.php" method="post">
            <a href="#" onclick="confirmDelete('<?php echo $x . $y; ?>'); return false;"><p><?php echo $aryClientInfo[$x][1][$y * 3]; ?></p></a>
            <input type="hidden" name="values<?php echo $x; ?>" value="<?php echo ($y * 3) . ',' . ($y * 3 + 1) . ',' . ($y * 3 + 2); ?>">
        </form>
```

instead of

```
onclick="confirmDelete(<?php echo $x . $y; ?>); return false;"
```

should be:

```
onclick="confirmDelete('<?php echo $x . $y; ?>'); return false;"
```

Comment: Although this will work fine, inline function calls should be avoided. The click event should be bound to the <a> tag and not placed in the inline onClick="". Will keep your code much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working jsfiddle without php code embedded, it might help you:

https://jsfiddle.net/eq0ggxkf/

```
<body>
    <form name="form123" id="form123" action="/index.php" method="post">
            <a href="#" onclick="confirmDelete('123'); return false;"><p>some content</p></a>
            <input type="hidden" name="values" value="secret">
    </form>
        hello
</body>
<script>
    function confirmDelete( varForm ) {
            var r = confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this entry?");

            if (r == true) {
                document.getElementById("form" + varForm).submit();
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you @brian . good point, definitely I will take care this in future.